# Why am I getting ConcurrentModificationException here?

Tags: java

I am trying to run the following code

```
class test {

    private static Set <Integer> list_of_files = new HashSet<Integer>();
    private static Iterator i = list_of_files.iterator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();
        while(list_of_files.size()<= 15)
        {
            list_of_files.add(random.nextInt(40));
        }
    
    int fist = (Integer)i.next();
    }
}
```

The above code is throwing **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**.

This does not happen when I declare the Iterator inside the main function.
Can someone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: The iterator is no longer clean

Comment: If may not modify the collection before calling `next()`. The iterator is created when the class is loaded, then you're calling `add()` before calling `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the Iterator inside the main function before the "while" loop, you still get the "ConcurrentModificationException"; But if you declare it after the "while" loop, it is ok.

The reason is as per spec, during iterating the java collection, any add or remove operation on the original collection could cause fast fail "ConcurrentModificationException".